# Can #ifndef ignore method or variable duplications?

Tags: c, conditional-compilation, ifndef

Consider the code.

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
//Code
#endif
```

Code can be following cases

```c
// Case 1: 
#define foo 0
```

```c
// Case 2:
void foo_method(){};
```

```c
// Case 3:
int foo;
```

`foo.h` is included in many C files. When I compile only the case 1 is without errors, other cases throw errors of duplication.

Why is so when the `foo.h` is not concatenated to C files except the one while compiling?

Comment: What do you expect when writing dodgy code? Good coding style prevents this as defines are always in capitals

Answer (score 7, accepted):

About case 2:
you should only declare the function signature, not the body. it has nothing to do with the pre-processor commands.

in the header file (decleration only)

```
#if <Condition>
void foo();
#endif
```

in the C file

```
#if <Condition>
void foo(){
   //body
}

#endif
```

about case 3:
it's similar to case 2, with the addition that you should declare variables in the header file if they are *extern* , there is no need to declare them in a header file otherwise. if they *are* declared as extern, they also need to be declared in a C file without the extern keyword:

in the header file:

```
#if <Condition>
extern int bar;
#endif
```

in the C file:

```
#if <Condition>
int bar;
#endif
```